# How can I find the best start and finish frames for looping a video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, software-recommendation

Is there a way I can programmatically identify an ideal start and finish frame for looping a video using freely available or open source tooling such as ffmpeg?

I found [this solution](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19869/finding-the-place-where-a-video-loops) which is close, but looks for an exact frame. I need to just find some best frames out of whats available in a given video.

The videos in my use case are moderately complex, mostly a single person with a still  camera.